# Java MongoDB Driver / Reference

Tags: java, mongodb

I am extremely new to Java and am trying to connect to a local MongoDB instance on my machine.  I've downloaded the respective jars and POM files from the following Mongo repo: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/?_ga=1.267751309.284881865.1476985525

I downloaded the files into the same directory where my script lives and ran JavaC, which has thrown a number of **"does not exists"** and **"cannot find symbol"** errors.

I am running MongoDB 3.2, and have downloaded the most recent (3.3) version of the Mongo jars/pom..

Here is my script:

```
// includes
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MongoDBJDBC {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
                // To connect to mongodb server
                MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017 );

                // Now connect to your database
                DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
                System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
                boolean auth = db.authenticate(myUserName, myPassword);
                System.out.println("Authentication: "+auth);

        }
        catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() +" "+ e.getMessage() );
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the those details (provided in the comment) to your post. Rename your file to `MongoDBJDBC.java`.

Comment: any IDE you are using ?